# Open() with O_WRONLY blocks even though I open() with O_RDONLY on the other end

Tags: c, named-pipes

I am facing the exact problem that the title says.

CODE

```
pid_t childpid;
int childfdRead, childfdWrite; // file descriptors for childs
int parentfdsRead[numWorker], parentfdsWrite[numWorker]; // file descriptors for parent

// store the fifo filenames
char *childPipeNameRead[numWorker];
char *childPipeNameWrite[numWorker];

// helper string to construct fifo filenames
char *suffix = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
char *fifoname = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));

for(i = 0; i < numWorker; i++){
    // Fifo filename structure read
    sprintf(fifoname, "%s", PATH);
    sprintf(suffix, "_childRead%d", i);
    childPipeNameRead[i] = strdup(strcat(fifoname, suffix));
    mkfifo(childPipeNameRead[i], 0666);

    // Fifo filename structure write
    sprintf(fifoname, "%s", PATH);
    sprintf(suffix, "_childWrite%d", i);
    childPipeNameWrite[i] = strdup(strcat(fifoname, suffix));
    mkfifo(childPipeNameWrite[i], 0666);

    childpid = fork();

    if(childpid < 0){
        perror("fork\n");
    }

    else if(childpid == 0){
        // Open read and write pipes on childs.
        if((childfdRead = open(childPipeNameRead[i], O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) < 0)
            perror("child pipe:");

        printf("Child with id %d opened pipe with name %s\n", getpid(), childPipeNameRead[i]);

        if((childfdWrite = open(childPipeNameWrite[i], O_WRONLY)) < 0)
            perror("child pipe:");

        printf("Child with id %d opened pipe with name %s\n", getpid(), childPipeNameWrite[i]);
        break;
    }
    else{
        // Open read and write pipes for each child in the parent process.
        if((parentfdsRead[i] = open(childPipeNameRead[i], O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) < 0)
            perror("parent pipe:");
        printf("Parent with id %d opened pipe with name %s\n", getpid(), childPipeNameRead[i]);

        if((parentfdsWrite[i] = open(childPipeNameWrite[i], O_WRONLY)) < 0)
            perror("parent pipe:");
        printf("Parent with id %d opened pipe with name %s\n", getpid(), childPipeNameWrite[i]);
    }
}
```

The program hangs after the parent and one child open their read pipe (parent opens only one of them). Is this normal behaviour? I was expecting it to open all pipes since I am using `O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK` for both the parent and the child.

Comment: What is `numWorker` and where is it initialized or defined? And why do you allocate `suffix` and `fifoname` dynamically instead of using plain arrays? Why have those temporary variables in the first place, when you can just make `childPipeNameRead` and `childPipeNameWrite` arrays of arrays, and `snprintf` directory into them? Like e.g. `snprintf(childPipeNameRead[i], sizeof childPipeNameRead[i], "%s_childRead%d", PATH, i)` Less chance of something going wrong, and less memory leaks (which you *do* have now).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh god you are right this must be reversed.
`numWorker` is a command line argument. Your code for `childPipeNameRead and Write` is giving me a Seg Fault though.
EDIT: Yeah my bad did not change `childPipeNameWrite` to and array of arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you open `childPipeNameRead[i]` for reading in *both* the child and parent process. And similarly you open `childPipeNameWrite[i]` for writing in both processes.

You need to do the opposite in one of the processes.

Comment: Yeah that fixed it. Now I feel stupid for not noticing that earlier.

Comment: @Akaitenshi Don't worry, it happens to everyone. Having a few others look at your code always help.